# RegEx to check the string contains least one alphabet or digit

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want a `regular expression` that check `string` must contain least an alphabet `[a-zA-Z]` or a `digit`. All other `special characters` are allowed, but only `special characters` or only `spaces` or `only spaces with special characters` will now be accepted.

I have tried `/\b(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])[\s\S]\b/i` and `^(a-zA-Z0-9).*[\s\S]*$` and `^(a-zA-Z0-9).*[\s].*[\S]*$` etc. But its not working. Awaiting for your valuable response.

Thanks

Comment: Why are your attempts so complex?  You define a character class as `[A-Za-z0-9]`; why do you need all that other stuff?

Comment: If I use only that much then space is not allowed. I want the string can have any character that doesn't metter, but it must have at least one digit or one alphabet.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what matches and what doesn't? What is meant that special characters *or* special character with spaces are allowed?

Comment: I've voted to close this as being too localized. There are many such questions on SO dealing with "at least one...", but in this case (I believe) the user mistakenly included regex delimiters where none were expected. Since the question asked isn't related to the delimiters, and everyone's solutions (including mine) focused on the regex, not the delimiters, this question isn't likely to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[\w\d]).+
```

This pattern will fail if there is not **at least** *one character* or *one digit* with any combination of *special characters and spaces*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but from what I've gathered you want to have atleast one letter (a-z, 0-9) in the string. This regex will do just that: `/^(?=.*[a-z\d]).+/igm`

(Set the flags however they need to be set in asp.net. The `m`-flag might be redundant for you, I only used it for the demo. The `g`-flag likely does not exist. If so, just remove it.)

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/jY9fJ5

Answer (score 1):

If you want at least one alphabet or digit, followed by only spaces and symbols:

```
/^.*[a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

If you want *only* one alphabet or digit, followed by the same:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

I can't imagine what else it is that you are looking for. Examples would help immensely.

Comment: This fails in string "dfdfdf #$#$ fgf ( gd )". I want that string must have at least an alphabet or a digit. Only special characters or spaces should not be allowed as a string.

Comment: @bcurcio Nope ! My regular expression validator is giving error message. <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revT" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtC" ErrorMessage="Error" 
                            ValidationGroup="a" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: @bcurcio Or you can also check with "df s 7*&* (fdf) 009 Df (dfd)"

Comment: Maybe it's a asp syntax thing. Try this `^.*[a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]*$`.

Comment: @Dev Your error message shows you are using the second option. That one accepts only 1 digit or character. Use the first one if you want to accept multiple characters

Comment: @bcurcio Have you tried both expressions on both the strings? I tried both and giving error. That is not asp.net thing man. Either string is failed in any one of them. Try yourself.

Comment: @Dev - I don't think you're supposed to add the delimiters (the slashes) in the `ValidationExpression` attribute. Try my first one without the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Za-z]).+
Allows special characters and makes sure at least one number and one letter.

(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*[^0-9A-Za-z]).+
Demands at least one letter, one digit and one special-character.
```

The first one does not demand special chars, only allows them.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.